# Undone vs Not done

Tags: meaning

I'm used to the pair 'Undo/Redo' in various programs, so I assumed that 'undone' means that 'something was done and reverted later', not just 'planned but not finished' or 'not yet completed'.

But [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/undone) just gives 'not done' as a synonym, without this subtle meaning that I presumed.
Can somebody clarify this for me, please?

Comment: The planned renovation of the kitchen still remains undone.  I agree with M-W.

Comment: @GEdgar I agree with Amomum that there is additional meaning to "undone" that is not reflected in M-W's definition. [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/undone) gives three senses, including one that fits the literary "I am undone!" usage.  [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/undone) points you to "undo" for additional information about its adjectival usage.

Comment: Strangely, M-W gives an example which does not fit their definition: "what’s been done can be just as easily undone."  So, they seem to recognize this use too!

Comment: @Juhasz That sentence is ambiguous. *Undone* **could** mean "reversed" or simply "not done" there. (Admittedly, it doesn't usually mean "not done", and MW's use of it as illustration is probably just perverse.)

Comment: As usual, negatives cause problems. The _un-_ prefix can mean **either** simply "not", as in _undone homework_, **or** "reverse activity", as in _unpack your luggage_. Not all activities can be reversed, so it's often a matter of context that determines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between the past participle of "*undo*" and the adjective "undone".  The OALD, as the Merriam-Webster dictionary does not take this meaning into account, but the SOED does (reversed, annuled).

> ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/undone?q=undone) **undone** adjective [not usually before noun]
> 1/ ​(especially of clothing) not fastened or tied
> ​2/ (especially of work) not finished
> 3/ ​(old use) (of a person) defeated and without any hope for the future

The SOED lists "undone" three times, two entries are adjectives and one is the  past participle of "undo".

> (SOED) **undone** *a.¹* Not done, unaccomplished, uneffected, incomplete.

> (SOED) **undone** *a.²* **1.** Ruined, destroyed; reversed, annulled.
> **2** Unfastened, untied, loosened

Answer (score 0):

In the context of IT **undo** is often a synonym for **roll back** or **uncommit**. These are terms which are specific to data processing and mean:

> reverse the process of updating the record or records you have just updated so that the database is restored to its previous state with respect to that set of records.

In the case of **hierarchic databases** this usually means to examine a set of actions in the database log and reverse them.

This is not the normal meaning of "undone" as defined in MW but it does have parallels in normal speech such as "undo a knot" which means "untie" and "undo all your good work" meaning to render what has been achieved void.